# xamrin android visual studio 2019 community version for WhatsApp chat with button click on specific number

Tags: android, xamarin.android, chat

I want to add button in my app. when I click on the button this will redirect me to WhatsApp chat having that specific number and chat with that number. I have the following code but its not working :(

```
  public void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string phoneNumberWithCountryCode = "+9233623xxx";
        string message = "Hallo";

        StartActivity(new Intent(
            Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phoneNumberWithCountryCode + "&text=" + message)));
    }


Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.watsapp_op);

        
      button1.Click += (sender, e) => {
        

         Button1_Click(sender, e);


        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the [working sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928787/8187800) , it sets `Package` in Intent , so try the following code .

```
private void OpenWhatsApp(Activity activity, string number, string message)
    {

        try
        {
            PackageManager packageManager = activity.PackageManager;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + URLEncoder.Encode(message, "UTF-8");
            i.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
            i.SetData(Uri.Parse(url));
            if (i.ResolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
            {
                activity.StartActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                //Error message
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // exception
        }

    }
```

##### Update

Does the button on the current content view or not ?

You can see `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main)`  in OnCreate method .

You have to ensure the button is placed in `activity_main.xml` , if the button is in another layout , you have to find the view first .

```
var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.anotherlayout,null);
var button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
```

Comment: I also try this it is also not working. Uri.parse gives error of deprecated

Comment: Use `Android.Net.Uri` not `System.Uri` , refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326433/uri-parse-deprecated.

Comment: I have tried this too but nothing happens :( actually, I tried with a simple button click but my button doesn't catch the click event

Comment: button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.watsapp_op);


            button.Click += delegate
            {

                OpenWhatsApp(this, "+9233362xxxx", "hi");

            };

Comment: also tried this button click evet code too      button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.watsapp_op);


            button.Click += (sender, e) => 
            {

                OpenWhatsApp(this, "+9233362315679", "hi");

            };

Comment: Check my update .

Comment: I have a button in my xml file activity_main.xml and also I have initialize it in MainActivity.cs file

Comment: The code doesn't give any error. but button click not working :(

Comment: Could you try this on a new project to see if problem persists ? Because your code looks totally correct .

Comment: yeah I have tried with a new project too

Comment: Could you provide us a basic, reproducible project to test? You can upload to github and attach the link here .